# Traverse nested array items based on values provided in a string

Tags: php, arrays

How can I change a string like this...

```php
$string = 'a.b.c';
```

into something like this...

```php
$c = $array['a']['b']['c']
```

**Edit**

I have a multi-dimensional array called $array which looks something like this...

```php
[
   "id" => 1,
   "name" => 'Test A'
   "b" => [
     "id" => 1,
     "name" => "Test B"
     "c" => [
       "id" => 1,
       "name" => 'Test'
      ]
   ]
]
```

I need to traverse through those elements in the array to retrieve the element 'c' so I can then manipulate it elsewhere in the application.

Comment: What should be the output of $c ?

Comment: @ADyson I have a multi-dimensional array, and each of the items in the string are levels in the array. I need to basically traverse through and pluck it out. The string is dynamic and coming from another source but matches if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I've understood your array structure and your intentions correctly then you could traverse the structure something like this:

```
$string = 'a.b.c';
$array = array("a" => array ("b" => array( "c" => 42)));  

$values = explode(".", $string);
$out = $array;

foreach ($values as $val)
{
    $prev = $out;
    $out = $prev[$val];
}

echo $out;
```

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2ebc94f3227f6e0c2dcbc5377bc5c5c69a8ba86c

(There may be a more efficient and/or less verbose way but this way is a quick win, at least.)

Comment: Yes, this was exactly what I was looking for. It's an odd scenario but this'll work for what I need. Thanks.